# Apache stopped working after executing the command "node server"

Tags: node.js, ssh

I use PuTTY to execute SSH commands. I entered this command `node server` and pressed enter. After that, access to cPanel and WHM have failed. All my sites are down now. Only Power Panel is working. Could you guys suggest what should be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Does node use the same port as Apache? Can you tell node to stop again?

Comment: After running `node server` in PuTTY, it says that node is running at http://localhost:8888. I have successfully killed node in the Power Panel but my sites are still down.

Comment: PuTTY has started to fail as well.

Comment: Sorry, it is now resolved. I used SurfEasy VPN in order to access PuTTY via a proxy. I was able to send the command `pkill node` and my sites are now running again.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer my own question, it is now resolved. I used SurfEasy VPN in order to access PuTTY via a proxy. I was able to send the command `pkill node` and my sites are now running again.